# Wordpress Page Coming up with Error

Tags: stream

My website is coming up with the following error and I have no clue what to do at this point.

How can I fix it?

> Warning: require(/home/content/26/9036426/html/wp-includes/load.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/26/9036426/html/wp-settings.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/content/26/9036426/html/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /home/content/26/9036426/html/wp-settings.php on line 21

Comment: What part of **no such file or directory** is unclear to you?

Comment: why would it all of the sudden do this? how do i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)